# Extracting time from logs using tcl, expect

Tags: scripting, expect, tcl

I have logs with the following pattern:

```
1,30.10.2014,07:51:07,0,0,1,12,28,255,3,255,255,255,0,0,0;
2001,30.10.2014,07:51:07,0,0,0,300,5,0,255;
```

I need to extract date and time... for the first line I Do the following:

```
set starttime [string range $procline 2 20]
```

But how can I extract it if the identifier (the code before the time) is longer?
I'm using expect (tcl). I tried matching the string, but maybe I'm doing something wrong. The line is already loaded as `$procline`.

I tried many different ways from other answers I've found here in the forums, but nothing really worked out for me.

Comment: is it separated by comma all through log file and date and time is always after 1st and 2nd comma ??

Comment: %EVENT_CODE,%DATE,%TIME,$parameter1,$parameter2...; all the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tcl:

```
set fields [split $procline ,]
set timestamp [join [lrange $fields 1 2]]
set time [clock scan $timestamp -format "%d.%m.%Y %T"]
```

Or, in one shot:

```
set time [clock scan [join [lrange [split $procline ,] 1 2]] -format "%d.%m.%Y %T"]
```

Comment: No go, something lame is happening.

Comment: `expected integer but got "30.10.2014 07:51:07"
    while executing
"ParseFormatArgs {*}$args"
    (procedure "::tcl::clock::format" line 6)
    invoked from within
"::tcl::clock::format {30.10.2014 07:51:07} -format {%d.%m.%Y %T}"`

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Should be `clock scan`, not `clock format`

Comment: Beautiful!!!! Thanks so much! (I'm a bit new here, please let me know how I can flag your answer as correct).

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

using awk

```
awk -F ',' '{print $2,$3}' log_file.txt
```

if date and time is in 2nd and 3rd position separated by comma

you can do like this if you to store variable

```
while read x;do a=`echo $x | awk -F ',' '{print $2,$3}'`;
#now do whatever you want to do with your variable 
done < log_file.txt
```

Comment: This won't help me much I think.


If I try to spawn awk, I can't use the variable I have. My whole line is already in a variable. Unless I perhaps process the text file first, generate a cleaner file, and then use expect to do my magic.

Comment: may be edited code will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `awk` you are able to use just `bash bultins`

```
 IFS=, read a MY_DATE MY_TIME b <<< $procline ; echo $MY_DATE $MY_TIME
```